# Cant get Mysql trigger statement right

Tags: mysql, triggers

Can someone please tell me whats wrong with this trigger statement?

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER something AFTER INSERT ON sometable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE var INT DEFAULT 0;
SET var = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anothertable;
IF var=0 THEN
INSERT INTO anothertable values(`x`,`y`,`z`);
END IF;
END//
```

I keep getting error saying i have syntax errors...

Comment: Are these backticks (`) or single quotes (') around x, y, and z. It looks like backticks, but should be quotes.

Comment: I have put single quotes too... doesnt work..

Comment: Please can you post a real example, as it feels like something is being lost in translation as it looks as a UNIQUE index or some other mechanic may be of use, just can't advise with partial data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the SELECT statement within brackets:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER something AFTER INSERT ON sometable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE var INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET var = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anothertable);
    IF var=0 THEN
        INSERT INTO anothertable values('x','y','z');
   END IF;
END//
```